# How to express explicit and implicit rules in Snakemake?

Tags: snakemake

In order to understand [Snakemake](https://bitbucket.org/snakemake/snakemake/wiki/Home), I want to compare a traditional Makefile example with Snakemake. There is a [nice introduction page to make](http://www.jfranken.de/homepages/johannes/vortraege/make_inhalt.en.html) with an educational example for prerequisites:

```
# source: http://www.jfranken.de/homepages/johannes/vortraege/make_inhalt.en.html

# Declaration of a variable
clothes = coat shoes mobile sweater socks\
        trousers shirt pants undershirt

all: $(clothes)

# An explicit rule assigns the commands for several targets
$(clothes):
    @echo put on $@; touch $@

# Implicit rules state the prerequisites
coat:      shoes mobile sweater
shoes:     socks trousers
mobile:    trousers
sweater:   shirt
trousers:  pants shirt
shirt:     undershirt

# Additional feature
.PHONY: naked
naked:      ; @-rm $(clothes)
```

I tried to translate this into a Snakemake file, see the end of this post. It works, but I have to repeat the `touch` command for every article. I tried to copy make's approach by distinguishung between explicit and implicit rules (using wildcards), but didn't succeed. Is there a more elegant way than my current one?

```
# Snakemake version of http://www.jfranken.de/homepages/johannes/vortraege/make_inhalt.en.html#ToC6

CLOTHES = ["coat", "shoes", "mobile", "sweater", "socks", "trousers", "shirt", "pants", "undershirt"]

rule all:
    input: CLOTHES

rule coat:
    input: "shoes", "mobile", "sweater"
    output: "coat"
    shell: "touch coat"

rule shoes:
    input: "socks", "trousers"
    output: "shoes"
    shell: "touch shoes"

rule mobile:
    input: "trousers"
    output: "mobile"
    shell: "touch mobile"

rule sweater:
    input: "shirt"
    output: "sweater"
    shell: "touch sweater"

rule trousers:
    input: "pants", "shirt"
    output: "trousers"
    shell: "touch trousers"

rule shirt:
    input: "undershirt"
    output: "shirt"
    shell: "touch shirt"

rule undershirt:
    output: "undershirt"
    shell: "touch undershirt"

rule pants:
    output: "pants"
    shell: "touch pants"

rule socks:
    output: "socks"
    shell: "touch socks"


### Additional feature

rule naked:
    run:
        for ds in CLOTHES:
            shell("rm -f {}".format(ds))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Snakemake, one would use [input functions](https://bitbucket.org/snakemake/snakemake/wiki/Documentation#markdown-header-functions-as-input-files) and a config file for varying dependencies, e.g.:

```python
configfile: "config.yaml"


def get_prereqs(wildcards):
    """Lookup prerequisites in config file."""
    # return prereqs as list of strings
    return config["clothes"][wildcards.type]


# target rule for creating all desired files
rule all:
    input:
        config["clothes"]


rule clothes:
    input:
        # refer to function that will be called with the inferred wildcards as single argument
        get_prereqs
    output:
        # in general, rule output should be more specific than in this example
        "{type}"
    shell:
        "touch {output}"
```

And the config.yaml:

```yaml
clothes:
  coat:
    - shoes
    - mobile
    - sweater
  shoes:
    - socks
    - trousers
  mobile:
    - trousers
  sweater:
    - shirt
  trousers:
    - pants
    - shirt
  shirt:
    - undershirt
  pants: []
  undershirt: []
  socks: []
```

Comment: Dear Johannes, might be there is a small typo there? In the yaml file, I think "prerequisites" should be "clothes" instead. In the Snakefile, you are using "clothes".

Comment: Thank you @johannes-köster, this looks good. In addition to @Fernandez correction, you also need to explicity specify pants, undershirt and socks with `pants: []` etc. I've revised the answer accordingly.

Comment: Alternatively, you can use `return config["clothes"].get(wildcards.type, [])` in the function.